# How can i fix javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch

Tags: android, sdk, mismatch

[image]

[image]

I start download the android studio from https://developer.android.com/studio for my new system
I retry to fix the problem but it cannot installed. Please tell us why?
how to install the latest version.
We does not experience the previous versions of android studio.